# Trigger another route with a query string inside Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jruby

I am writing a route that bundles the response of several routes together so I need to trigger other routes from within Sinatra. I found this code in the Sinatra README to do that:

```
status, headers, body = call env.merge("PATH_INFO" => '/bar')
```

It doesn't, however, send the query string. So I tried this:

```
status, headers, body = call env.merge(
    "PATH_INFO" => '/bar', 
    "QUERY_STRING" => 'param=1'
)
```

That doesn't seem to work. How can I call another route and pass the query string such that the values in the string end up in the params hash of the called route.

We are using Sinatra 1.3.1 and Rack 1.3.5.

Comment: beside my answer below why don't you put your route logic into helper methods that you can call from either route? That calling multiple routes from one other route doesn't sound like a good design decision.

Comment: Its a back-fill to improve application loading performance. The alternative is a bunch of GET requests from the browser.

Comment: No, the alternative, like @three suggests, is to move the contents of your routes to helper methods that pass the param values explicitly, and then call those methods when you need to aggregate results. Note also that there are [bugs](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/452) [introduced](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/453) in Sinatra 1.3.2 surrounding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your 2 cents. I understood his suggestion. I isn't viable since it requires re-writing dozens of routes. Sometimes reality interferes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the solution is to clear out the `@original_params` variable. Clearly, even if it appears in the Sinatra README this is not supported. Time permitting I'd rework my routes so this isn't required, but there you are.

```
@original_params = nil
status, headers, body = call env.merge(
    "PATH_INFO" => '/bar', 
    "QUERY_STRING" => 'param=1'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the params to route like this `"/bar?param=1&anotherparam=3"`

Comment: what do the logs say? Could you output the `params` var? Maybe put it into a before filter.